# Path from Math.SE to Meta Math.SE in the review tab. Why not the reverse path?

Tags: feature-request, review

In the review tab where the different review queues are listed there is a direct link to the review tab of Meta (which I like very much). I think it would be useful to have a similar path from the review tab of Meta to the review tab of the main website.

I think it would be very helpful to have such a link so that one can just quickly check if there is a review task in meta and then come back to the review tasks of the main site in one click (actually I click on my account, click on "main user" and then click again on "review" to come back).

Another solution would be to merge the review tabs, however I don't think it is a good idea since the quality criteria in Meta and the main website are very different.

Is it already possible in **one** click? (in which case, please retag my question with *support*)

Is there a good reason for this link not to be there?

What do you think?

Comment: I don't know if there's a good reason for it not to be there, but it's probably just that's there's no good reason for it to be there. My guess: on other websites with more volume than here (SO...) the review queue in meta grew very large because not enough people cared about going through it, so they added the link to direct a bit of traffic there. Anyway, if you're in the meta RQ, you can just remove the word "meta" from your URL bar and you will land on the main RQ. More than one click, but not a lot either.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi ok makes sense. "there's no good reason for it to be there" well I think the reason I gave is not that bad (even-though I have to admit that it is not an amazing argument)... I don't know how hard to implement this would be, but this would be the only good reason (IMO) to not do it. So... why not doing it...?

Comment: Reviews on meta is a one-way street. Once you're down that black hole, there's no hope to return back.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it's like a trap to keep the people on meta :).

Comment: And it works. Look at me. I've been here for years.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually it worked also for me. I first started to really get interested in Meta since there is this link :). But I'm not sure that the reverse link would kill the effect of the trap.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Open the meta review queue in a new tab.

Comment: @AlexR Yes this suggestion is convincing me even more than that of Najib. Another way is to use the fact that there are very rarely review tasks in meta and so to just go on the previous page. But still... these kind of artificial ways...